# How to get the request payload in the response-- ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

have an ajax method, which uses post. the response should come under request payload, but it is coming as query string parameter.

Method ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<url>',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(object)
});
```

Current Output:

```
Query String Parameter : Object
```

Expected output :

```
Request Payload : Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/:

> data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the server. **It is converted to a query string, if not already a string**. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processDataoption to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Try to change your data to something like that:

```
data: {obj: JSON.stringify(object)}
```